# Python: Sampling from a discrete distribution defined in an n-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

Is there a function in Python that samples from an n-dimensional numpy array and returns the indices of each draw. If not how would one go about defining such a function?

E.g.:

```
>>> probabilities = np.array([[.1, .2, .1], [.05, .5, .05]])  
>>> print function(probabilities, draws = 10)
 ([1,1],[0,2],[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,1],[1,1],[0,0],[1,1],[0,1])
```

I know this problem can be solved in many ways with 1-D arrays. However, I will be dealing with large n-dimensional arrays and can not afford to reshape them just to do a single draw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html):

```
a = np.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
a /= a.sum()

def sample(a, n=1):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    choices = np.prod(a.shape)
    index = np.random.choice(choices, size=n, p=a.ravel())
    return np.unravel_index(index, dims=a.shape)

>>> sample(a, 4)
(array([2, 2, 0, 2]), array([0, 1, 3, 2]), array([2, 4, 2, 1]))
```

This returns a tuple of arrays, one per dimension of `a`, each of length the number of samples requested. If you would rather have an array of shape `(samples, dimensions)`, change the return statement to:

```
return np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(index, dims=a.shape))
```

And now:

```
>>> sample(a, 4)
array([[2, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 4],
       [2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If your array is contiguous in memory, you can change the `shape` of your array in place:

```
probabilities = np.array([[.1, .2, .1], [.05, .5, .05]]) 
nrow, ncol = probabilities.shape
idx = np.arange( nrow * ncol ) # create 1D index

probabilities.shape = ( 6, ) # this is OK because your array is contiguous in memory

samples = np.random.choice( idx, 10, p=probabilities ) # sample in 1D
rowIndex = samples / nrow # convert to 2D
colIndex = samples % ncol

array([2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0])
array([1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Note that since your array is contiguous in memory, `reshape` returns a view as well:

```
In [53]:

view = probabilities.reshape( 6, -1 )
view[ 0 ] = 9
probabilities[ 0, 0 ]
Out[53]:
9.0
```

Comment: Thanks, how would this generalize to n-dimensions?